# File module not updating field

Tags: 7, files

I have a File field for uploading pdfs. When editing the page, I remove the current pdf and upload a new pdf. The new pdf is uploaded to the server and add to the /sites/default/files folder and I can access the new pdf. However, the page still references the previous pdf that was uploaded.

I check the database and noticed that the new pdf was added to the files_managed and the files_usage tables but NOT the files table. Any idea why this would be and how I can get the File field to reference the latest uploaded pdf?

In a template, I have a db query for the file id, when I print the fid on the page, it shows the outdated file id instead of the new file id.

Answer (score 0):

Are you clicking Save at the bottom of the edit page after uploading the new PDF?

You need to do this to save the file reference in the node field.

Comment: Yes, I am clicking save at the bottom of the edit page.

Comment: Anything in dblog related to saving the node?

Comment: No, nothing related to saving the node. The file reference doesn't even update to nothing when I simply remove the file without replacing it.